# How to draw an SVG Polyline in right to left direction using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG Polyline in Left to Right (LTR) mode as follows:

```
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"
    points="05,30
            15,30
            15,20
            25,20
            25,10
            35,10" />
 </svg>
```

How to draw this same line in Right to Left (RTL) mode? Should I be using transform or translate properties?

Comment: What is left to right mode? What then would right to left mode be? Do you just want the shape drawn mirrored about its centre in the vertical axis?

Comment: I am referring to the global direction attribute which is by default is ltr (left to right) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp  And Yes, Robert, you are right about the shape re-drawn mirrored. That would be actually the solution for the question and I am trying to figure out how to achieve it. And I finally did it by doing this transform = translate($somewidth, 0) scale(-1,1). This gave me the mirror image of the SVG in RTL mode!

Comment: The global direction attribute is about text only. There's no such thing as left to right for graphics.

Comment: Oh. True. Hence, I am redrawing the mirror image whenever I am in RTL mode. :)

Comment: Sorry about that! I will write it up. @RobertLongson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my question was to simply re-draw the SVG's mirror image. This can be done by using transform, translate and scale properties as below:

```
transform = "translate($width, 0) scale(-1,1)"
```

Here, scale() function is used as a mirror function by scaling by -1 along either the x-axis or y-axis.

Code:

```
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"
    points="05,30
            15,30
            15,20
            25,20
            25,10
            35,10" transform="translate(50,0) scale(-1, 1)"/>
 </svg>
```

Note: As Robert mentioned in the comments, the global direction attribute is only applicable to text elements but not to the graphic elements. So, in my js file, I check if the direction is rtl or not and then display the mirrored svg if it is true.

The link for the fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ShellZero/vzaoysw7/5/

The following two links helped me out in solving my problem: 
 
[1] https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/ 
[2] https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Introduction